# Executing Simulink model by m-File and retrieving the results

Tags: matlab, simulink

maybe this might be a simple problem but after a long while at Google and the search function I didn't find any answer to the following question:

I have a simulink model which need some input params. I want this model to be executed in a loop with different params each run. How do I do this?

And how am I able to retrieve the output of my model in order to use them for further operations in the m-file? Do I have any special block for giving the results out to my m-file? The bridge between simulink and matlab seems to me very unclear in this case...

Can someone help me understanding this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you need to use the `sim` command ([ref page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/sim.html), ["using sim command" page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/ug/f11-61836.html)) to run the model.

You need to set up the parameters for your model prior to each call to `sim`. There are multiple ways you can do this, but in the simplest case where you have a block with a parameter called, say, `N`, you might do something like this:

```
for ii = 1:3
   N = ii;
   simOut{ii} = sim( 'mymodel' );
end
```

To get stuff to show up in your simulation results structures (`simOut`), you should add root-level outport blocks.

As a concrete example, consider the standard demo model `vdp`. This has no parameters, but the following shows how to capture outputs:

```
simOut = sim( 'vdp', 'SaveOutput', 'on' );
results = simOut.get( 'yout' );
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer! Regarding to your "root-level outport" block...which exactly in the library browser is this? Easily using Sinks/Out in the main simulation model? If yes, how must I set the param? e.g. "x" as output variable does cause an error message.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, it works :) the only thing I'm still wondering is, where in the vdp-model itself the variable "yout" is definded (or is it a predefined universal constant?)